# Pandas dataframe to dict with unique values from coloumn as keys and nested lists as values

Tags: pandas, dictionary, dataframe, python-3.6, pandas-groupby

Im trying to convert a dataframe to a dict, with unique values from a coloumn (col 3) as keys.

From this:

```
  Col1   Col2   Col3
0  a       b      x
1  c       d      x
2  e       f      y
3  g       h      y
```

To this:

```
{x:[[a,b][c,d]],y:[[e,f],[g,h]]}
```

With the following code i get tuples, which really doesnt do the trick for me.

```
new_dict = df.groupby('col3').apply(lambda x: list(zip(x['col1'],x['col2']))).to_dict()
```

output:

```
{x:[(a,b),(c,d)],y:[(e,f),(g,h)]}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `map` to list or list comprehension:

```
new_dict = (df.groupby('col3')
              .apply(lambda x: list(map(list, zip(x['col1'],x['col2']))))
              .to_dict())
print (new_dict)
{'x': [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']], 'y': [['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h']]}
```

---

```
new_dict = (df.groupby('col3')
              .apply(lambda x: [list(y) for y in zip(x['col1'],x['col2'])])
              .to_dict())
```

Another solution is convert each group to 2d array and convert to `list`:

```
new_dict = df.groupby('col3')['col1','col2'].apply(lambda x: x.values.tolist()).to_dict()
```

Comment: Thanks for the very quick answer, it worked perfectly! Ill mark your answer as accepted as soon as i can (i have to wait 10 more minutes :))